# Trying to calcluate ISE with matlab throws an error

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to simulate a regulation object, however when trying to calculate ISE it throws an error:

Dimension argument must be a positive integer scalar within indexing range.

Here's my code:

```
A=[0 1; -8.6207 -10.0682];
B=[0 ; 1];
C=[34.4827 0];
D=0;
sys=ss(A,B,C,D);

Tp=0.01;
I=eye(2);
Ad=I+A*Tp;
Bd=B*Tp;
Cd=C;
Dd=D;
M=15/Tp;
y=zeros(1, M);
x= [0;0];
kp=12,97;
Ti=0.567;
tt=(1:M)*Tp;


for k = 2:M
    %regulator
     e=1-y(k-1);
     u=kp*(e+(1/Ti)*trapz(e));
    %obiekt
    x=Ad*x + Bd*u;
    y(k)=Cd*x + Dd*u;
    %wskaznik jakosci
    ise=trapz(tt,e.^2);
end
figure(1);
plot(tt,y);
figure(2);
plot(tt,ise)
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the line `ise=trapz(tt,e.^2);`. Here, `e` is a scalar while `tt` is a vector. According to [trapz documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html), if `tt` is a vector of coordinates, then `length(tt)` must be equal to the size of the first dimension of `e` whose size does not equal 1.

Comment: Yes, ise is the problematic part, tt is a vector of time or "steps" for this discrete object, my e is a numerical value, I've tried iterating with e(k) to create a matching vector of values, but it throws a whole other error.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do but have you tried `ise=trapz(e.^2, tt)`? Does it give a correct answer?

Comment: Another point is that you are not saving values of `ise` in every iteration. So, `plot(tt, ise)` will not provide anything meaningful, it will plot just a point (the final value of `ise`).

Comment: Precisely, I'm trying to save a vector of values of e in each iteration, however I can't figure out how to get that to work, so I want to save value of ise variable for every iteration, my ise  Integral Square Error, got any tips how to save that ise value from each iteration ? Also using ise=trapz(e.^2, tt) works, but returns just one value.

Comment: As a quick solution, use `ise(k) = trapz(.....)`.

Comment: Also, the syntax `kp=12,97;` is not correct. Should it be `kp = 12.97`?

Comment: Okay yeah, I implemented ise(k) and that does work!, also that kp syntax error has been corrected, thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Just converting the comments to an answer.

The main problem was that the variables inside the `trapz()` function were included in the wrong order. Another issue related to plotting was also solved by saving the values of `ise` from every iteration.

If `ise` is declared as a vector before the loop, then the warning about changing its size in every iteration won't be shown.

Code:

```matlab
A=[0 1; -8.6207 -10.0682];
B=[0 ; 1];
C=[34.4827 0];
D=0;
sys=ss(A,B,C,D);

Tp=0.01;
I=eye(2);
Ad=I+A*Tp;
Bd=B*Tp;
Cd=C;
Dd=D;
M=15/Tp;
y=zeros(1, M);
x= [0;0];
kp=12.97; %%%% <----Change
Ti=0.567;
tt=(1:M)*Tp;

ise = zeros(1, M); %%%% <----Change
for k = 2:M
    %regulator
     e=1-y(k-1);
     u=kp*(e+(1/Ti)*trapz(e));
    %obiekt
    x=Ad*x + Bd*u;
    y(k)=Cd*x + Dd*u;
    %wskaznik jakosci
    ise(k)=trapz(e.^2, tt); %%%% <----Change
end
figure(1);
plot(tt,y);
figure(2);
plot(tt,ise)
```

The 2nd figure:

[image]